# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

**ANSWER:** 
***Turns out it's a bug with Hibernate 5.2.0. I switched to 5.1.0 in my Maven repository and it works perfectly fine.***

So I've been testing things out with Hibernate and decided to add Spring. Upon adding Spring, I've spent around 2-3 hours going through multiple different errors, but this one has me stuck. I've searched on here as there's multiple questions about this, but they all have different answers that sadly don't work.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'regularUserDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSessionFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Spring-Configuration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK220mhr6bs12en0vy6s1gjy0lb]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Spring-Configuration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK220mhr6bs12en0vy6s1gjy0lb]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.test.app.main.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [Spring-Configuration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK220mhr6bs12en0vy6s1gjy0lb]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Attempt to resolve foreign key metadata from JDBC metadata failed to find column mappings for foreign key named [FK220mhr6bs12en0vy6s1gjy0lb]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl$ForeignKeyBuilderImpl.build(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl$ForeignKeyBuilderImpl.build(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKey(TableInformationImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.findMatchingForeignKey(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:707)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:504)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 26 more
```

Here's my spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.glimpsmedia.app" />
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />
   <context:annotation-config/>

   <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.glimpsmedia.app.model" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

Here's the DAO:

```
@Repository("regularUserDaoImpl")
public class RegularUserDaoImpl implements RegularUserDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
...
```

And finally, here's main:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Configuration.xml");

        RegularUserServiceImpl regularUserService = (RegularUserServiceImpl) context.getBean("regularUserServiceImpl");

        RegularUser regularUser = new RegularUser();
        regularUser.setFirstName("John");

        regularUserService.save(regularUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: check if this foreign key exist in db `FK220mhr6bs12en0vy6s1gjy0lb`.. also the field it points to ...

Comment: @redflar3 I found the corresponding foreign key, but I'm not sure why it throws an error? It's defined the same way as all of the other foreign keys. Any suggestions as to how to fix it? Not quite sure how I can fix it as the other foreign keys work properly.

Comment: You have not posted the entities that uses a foreign key, so the best is to recreate a FK manually or drop a database and recreate it from your entity model.

Comment: @RomanC So I have around 10 classes that all have foreign key references. They're in the package called `model`. Since classes in packages are sorted alphabetically, the first class in that package is what's causing the foreign key issue. So, I believe it's my `context: component-scan` may be wrong? It scans the `model` package, goes to the first class in the package, and when it hits the first foreign key declaration, it throws the error. I declared my OneToMany and ManyToOne mapping properly as it works with just Hibernate. Am I doing the scanning wrong?

Comment: When you scan your components you should include base packages for that beans are resided. That beans should be configured with your entity managers so you can build a session factory. Failing to do that results you application context failstart.

Comment: @RomanC Turns out it was a bug with hibernate 5.2.0. I switched to 5.1.0. and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug with Hibernate 5.2.0. I switched to 5.1.0 in my Maven repository and it works perfectly fine.